# Plugin `WordPress Importer` does not offer author name to export custom post

Tags: wordpress, export

I have installed and activate the `WordPress Importer` plugin. Now when I tried to export posts of `post` type it allows me to select `author`, `category`, `date`, `status`, etc option.

Problem is it does not show any option while trying to export posts of the custom post type.

Please consider the images to see what happen when select `post` & `mcq` as a post type ...
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have limited option in case of default export. You should try plugin called.

Export Plus (https://wordpress.org/plugins/export-plus/)